# how to publish comment to a post using facebook graph api explorer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I am using facebook graph api explorer to explore and test different things but getting no idea after even an extensive research that how to post comment against a post . I am doing this
[image]

This is the second try

[image]

Comment: And if you want to target a specific post, then your request path will certainly not start with `/me`

Comment: yes, that is a problem. I am not clear about the syntax that should be used in graph explorer. I have test so many things using GET but now I am struggling with this POST. Can you help me to understand it?

Comment: @john Did you figure it out?

Comment: @GMcLuhan yeah I have figured it out by using facebook api testing einvironment for developers.

Comment: @john Could you post an answer to this question containing the correct code? This helps other (like me) who are looking for the same thing you were looking for in june.

Comment: Can you please post an answer?

Comment: This question needs an answer.